# Model doesn't update from controller to directive template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've create directive to use custom autocomplete functionality.

```
app.directive('autocomplete', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            results: '=',
            getStrLength: '&',
            selectObj: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'shared/js/angular/directives/templates/autocomplete.html'
    };
});
```

here is view for directive

```
<input class="custom-autocomplete" ng-model="keyword" ng-keyup="getStrLength({word: keyword})" type="text" />

<div id='custom-autocomplete' ng-if="results" >
    <div class="object" ng-repeat="(country, groups) in results.value">
        <b class='flags flag_{{country| lowercase}}'></b>{{results.countries[country]}}
        <div class='object-first-level' ng-click="selectObj({obj: group})" ng-repeat='(city, group) in groups'>
            {{group.name}}
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

after "selectObj" function is executed $scope.keyword is updated but doesn't change in directives template

Here is function for click from controller

```
$scope.selectObj = function (obj) {
        $scope.autocompleteReusuls = '';
        $rootScope.keyword = obj.name;
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a function in that directive to update the scope and call it from the parent controller.

Comment: Yea, that was the trick... thank you.